# How to do shift left here

Tags: python

I have a class BitCode:

```
class BitCode:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.data = s
```

I want to create a function so that the bits can be shifted to the left by one.

The test code is:

```
b = BitCode('01000001')
b.shift()
```

How should I write the function shift here?

Comment: I don't understand -- why do you think that you can't use `self` when you write the method?

Comment: Yes, just reference `self.data` in your `shift` method.

Comment: Please repeat your tutorial on writing instance methods (the functions in a class for individual instances).  You *write* the function with `self`, but it is *implied* in the call.

Comment: Please show us the `shift` function you tried to write.

Comment: Also, note that Python already [has native support](https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#left-shift) for left shift, so you can use that unless writing your own function is a requirement.

Comment: `self.data += "0"`

Answer (score 2):

You can reference `self.data` in the function. You just need to put the function inside the class, like this:

```
class BitCode:
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.data = s 

    @property
    def shift(self):
        #code here

#use function

b = BitCode('01000001')
b.shift
```

Comment: Good point! I changed the property thing.

Comment: I'd say using a property is not necessary, because a property usually means getting some value, and here `shift` would return None. A simple method that mutates `self.data` would be enough. Also, the test code is calling a method (`b.shift()`), not a property.